# Merge video annotations using PDFtron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdftron

I am using PDFTron for merging and saving of video annotation. When I am trying to merge the video annotation it gives an error:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): ffmpeg.wasm is not ready, make sure you
> have completed load().

```
instance.UI.setHeaderItems(header => {
          header.push({
            type: 'actionButton',
            img: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M17 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7l-4-4zm-5 16c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm3-10H5V5h10v4z"/></svg>',
            onClick: async () => {

              // save the annotations
              const video = await videoInstance.getVideo();
              video.mergeAnnotations(
                // WebViewer instance
                instance,
              );
            }
          });
        });
```

Anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome had an update that disabled a required browser feature that allows the editing/exporting library, we use to work properly.

Due to the loss of the browser feature, which is out of our control, we cannot support video/audio editing on the client. It may become available again in the future but the state of said features are unclear.

As a workaround, only a server solution makes sense. We will add an API to our video package to export the video frames, with annotations, as images. These images can then be sent to a server you control, where the merging of these images back into the video will be performed. The FFmpeg software can be used to perform this operation and we will document how to do this.

If you have any questions, do not hesitate to reach out at support@pdftron.com.